# Fully robust message queue in Linux/BASH

Tags: linux, bash, message-queue, named-pipes

I'm trying to implement a message queueing system using a named pipe.  To read from the pipe I've used:

`pump_read=1`

`while [[ ${pump_read} -eq 1]]; do`

`IFS="|" read pump_f1 pump_f2 pump_f3 < queuefile`

`echo "${pump_f1}|${pump_f1}|${pump_f3} >> pump.log`

`done`

To write to the named pipe I've used

`echo "x|y|z" | ssh user@host "cat > queuefile"`

I'm using this method because the reader and writers may not be on the same hosts. Mostly this works but reasonably frequently I will get rows in my log of "||" as though an empty line has been written into the pipe.  I also have times when messages will disappear as though they never made it to the pipe.  I can see no reason for missing or blank messages.

Does anyone have any ideas what I need to look at here to ensure messages cannot be lost?  Am I looking at coding something in C/C++ rather than BASH? At some point I may want to post messages to the queue asynchronously which I'm not sure is possible with a named pipe due to blocking on the reading/writing processes, however normally this will all happen quickly enough the blocking won't be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are better off at using an existing message / job queue instead of writing your own.

Here is a good list: http://queues.io/